# Xcode indicates that nsurlsessiondownloadtask consumes massive amounts of memory

Tags: xcode, swift, memory-management, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using NSUrlSession and NSUrlSessionDownloadTask to download files from a server to my app.

When I am running my app written in Swift from Xcode and looking at the memory consumption gauge the memory consumed increases steadily as the files are downloaded corresponding roughly to the data fetched.

So when downloading 1 GB of files Xcode indicates that my app is using over 1 GB of memory.

This makes absolutely no sense since the downloaded data is saved on disk and not in memory.

Also the app will run without crashing which seems impossible if the reported memory usage is correct.

Have anyone else encountered this issue?